# How to align a specific piece of text to the right while inside a list environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

How would it be possible to get the \emph{*input*.} aligned to the right side of the page, and only that piece of text? But at the same time, I would like to keep the text that is sent to the right side of the page aligned on the left edge. So all the \emph's are on the right side of the page but are all aligned on the left edge.

I believe a picture would best explain:

[image: Historia de la Filosofía por Guillermo Fraile, pg 22]

```
La escala de los seres según la noción realista:
\begin{itemize}
    \item[A)] Simple. Acto puro. Forma pura. \emph{Dios.}
    \item[B)] Compuestos de acto y potencia, de esencia y existencia:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Subsistentes (formas separadas de la materia): \emph{Almas separadas.\footnote{O sea, ángeles}}
        \item No subsistentes (formas unidas a la materia): Entes móviles:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[a)] Vivientes:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item[1] Racionales (forma espiritual): \emph{Hombres.}
                \item[2] No racionales (forma inmaterial):
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item[α] Sensitivos: \emph{Animales.}
                    \item[β] No sensitivos: \emph{Vegetales.}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{enumerate}
            \item[b)] No vivientes (formas materiales): \emph{Minerales.}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code based on `eqparbox`, `moreenum` and `enumitem`. I defined an `\emphrbox` command, which does the trick (with certain limitations). All lists environments are `enumerate`, and I had to change the enumerate depth (the default is `4`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{enumitem, moreenum}
\renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label=\Alph*)}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label=\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate, 3]{label=\alph*), font=\itshape}
\setlist[enumerate, 4]{label=\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate, 5]{label=\greek*}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\emphrbox}[2][LR]{\dotfill\quad\eqparbox{#1}{\em #2}}
\begin{document}

\noindent La escala de los seres según la noción realista:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Simple. Acto puro. Forma pura. \emphrbox{Dios.}
    \item Compuestos de acto y potencia, de esencia y existencia:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Subsistentes (formas separadas de la materia): \emphrbox{Almas separadas.\footnote{O sea, ángeles}}
        \item No subsistentes (formas unidas a la materia): \\Entes móviles:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Vivientes:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Racionales (forma espiritual): \emphrbox{Hombres.}
                \item No racionales (forma inmaterial):
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Sensitivos: \emphrbox{Animales.}
                    \item No sensitivos: \emphrbox{Vegetales.}
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}
            \item No vivientes (formas materiales): \emphrbox{Minerales.}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,parskip}
\begin{document}

\def\labelenumi{\Alph{enumi})}
\newlength{\nombremaslargo}
\settowidth{\nombremaslargo}{Hermenegilda}
\def\hermanas#1{\dotfill~~\makebox[\nombremaslargo][l]{\em #1}}

Juana y su hermana: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Con \verb-enumerate- \hermanas{Juana} 
    \item y una macro  \hermanas{Hermenegilda}
\end{enumerate}

Juana y su hermana: 

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.6}\tabcolsep2pt
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX>{\em }l}
    A)  & Con \verb-\dotfill- \dotfill & Juana \\
    B)  & y \verb-tabularx- \dotfill & Hermenegilda \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```